# Lines of Code modified in each Commit in TFS rest API. How do I get?

Tags: azure-devops

In TFS API only allow getting the modified file count only. But needed to get each file modified line count (added/deleted) for each commit in the rest call.

Answer (score 9):

There isn’t officially released REST API to do that. But you can refer to these steps to achieve your requirements.

1. [Get a list of commits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#get-a-list-of-commits) to get a commit’s commitId.
2. [Get a specific commit with its commitId](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#get-a-commit) to get parents value and repository id (The value at the end of _links>Repository>href) (Using the URL of _links>Changes>href can get file path if you don’t know)
3. Get file diff by this **POST** request `https://[account].visualstudio.com/[team project name] /_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters=[data 1]&repositoryId=[repository id]`

The [data 1] value should be formatted with JSON and have the following values (remove whitespace):

```json
{
    "originalPath":"/index.html",
    "originalVersion":"GC[a parent value, step 2]",
    "modifiedPath":"/index.html(path: step 2)",
    "modifiedVersion":"GC[commit id]",
    "partialDiff":true,
    "includeCharDiffs":true
}
```

The result contains this (you need to calculate the items that `changeType` isn’t equal to 0, 2 means remove, 1 means add):

```json
{
    "changeType": 2,
    "mLine": 9,
    "mLines": [],
    "mLinesCount": 0,
    "oLine": 9,
    "oLines": [
      "    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->"
    ],
    "oLinesCount": 1
  },
{
    "changeType": 1,
    "mLine": 22,
    "mLines": [
      "      <div>2</div>"
    ],
    "mLinesCount": 1,
    "oLine": 23,
    "oLines": [],
    "oLinesCount": 0
}
```

You can capture the request URL of a commit (History > Commits > Select a commit) by using [Developer Tools Network capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I coundn't understand the 3rd step.Can u pls explain what is the url for POST request and Request body and query parameter if it have.

Comment: @bhuvaneswarikalimuthu There isn't the request body, just in query parameter. I have already explain the parameters (?__v=5&diffParameters=[data 1]&repositoryId=[repository id]), the first one (data 1) is the JSON data, there is the sample in my answer, and the other parameter is repository id. What's parameter you unclear?

Comment: Thanks..Working...But this api is not mentioned anywhere in the TFS rest api reference.

Comment: can you suggest me the "scope" to enable for this api. 

I tried with **vso.code_manage vso.code_status vso.project vso.work**. But have 401 authorized error by using token with this scope

Comment: @bhuvaneswarikalimuthu Yes, it isn't a released API and not mentioned anywhere, I captured the request through Developer Tools. I don't understand clearly about 'scope', how did you try it?

Comment: I create oauth application with code_manage(read,write) and code_status(Manage) permission in my TFS account.and using this appid and secret id I created oauth token.By using that token access this api  I get 401 unauthorized error.But by using this token I can able to get other api calls like get pullRequests.

Comment: @bhuvaneswarikalimuthu I am afraid that you can use oauth token. For general REST API, it has api-version, but this request is different.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT. Any other way to get this count by rest call?

Comment: @bhuvaneswarikalimuthu There isn't the way to get count directly, you can calculate the items (e.g count items that changetype is 1)

Comment: Count items means count the files which  edited or added/deleted

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT hi I tried it today and I get 404. Maybe the endpoint in step 3 has changed. Do you know what's the current endpoint is?

Comment: Do note that you will get 404 if the file was created in the last commit: there is no diff to fetch prior to this commit because it didn't exist.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT if the commit has changes in several files, it means we need to make a call for each file. Any known way to make 1 call for the whole commit?