# Is there a way to get the amount of lines changed in a Pull Request via the Dev Ops Service REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, devops-services

I am currently doing my thesis and analyzing the behavior for code reviews. For this I want to know the size of the pull request that is reviewed. The rest of the information for example authors, reviewers, times etc. I got already by calling the rest API. However I cannot seem to find a way to get the amount of lines changed in each file, or a total number (which is also sufficient).

I have browsed the documentation and found some ways to get amount of files changed, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1. However, I didn't found a way to get the amount of changed lines per file or a total amount.

So is there a way to get amount of lines changed in a Pull Request or between two commits?

Answer (score 4):

For your issue , I am afraid that there is currently no official released REST API to do that. A similar question has been answered in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get) ,please refer to it for details, you can refer to these steps to achieve your requirements:

1.[Get a list of commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-a-list-of-commits) to get a commit’s commit id.

2.Get a commit by commit id (steps 1) to get parents value and repository id (The value at the end of _links>Repository>href) (Using the URL of _links>Changes>href can get file path if you don’t know)

3.Get file diff by this POST request 
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/ _api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters=[data 1]&repositoryId=[repository id]`

You could also add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions,our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.