# Calculate lines of code change for a commit?

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops, pull-request

Is there a way to calculate lines of code in a [Pull Request API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in Azure Devops for each file. I have gone through below two links and but was not of much help.

[Is there a way to get the amount of lines changed in a Pull Request via the Dev Ops Service REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569620/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-amount-of-lines-changed-in-a-pull-request-via-the-dev)

[Lines of Code modified in each Commit in TFS rest api. How do i get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get)

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Lines of code changed is not a reliable metric for anything.

Comment: Just another requirement :(

Comment: What's wrong with this question that it was closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps:

**a.** Get the [commit IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20commits/get%20pull%20request%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) for the specified pull request

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/commits?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

**b.** Get [commit path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) via the commit ID

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=5.0
```

**c.** Get [parents commit ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) via commit ID

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=5.0
```

**d.** Get the result via below API and request body.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{Project name}?api-version=5.1-preview
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-code-web.file-diff-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "repositoryId": "{Repo ID}",
      "diffParameters": {
        "includeCharDiffs": true,
        "modifiedPath": "{Commit path}",
        "modifiedVersion": "GC{Commit ID}",
        "originalPath": "{Commit path}",
        "originalVersion": "GC{parents commit ID}",
        "partialDiff": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and I'll try to get difference from master repository rather than between commits. any help will be appreciated. 
Also, In pull request, suppose there are 20 commits I only need to get difference between final commit version and master version.

Comment: Hi @AjayVerma,  Do you mean list all difference? If you could get it in the UI, could you share the screenshot result here? And we could get it via F12.

Comment: Hi,
Yes. I mean all difference for [final iteration files i.e. iteration count is 2](GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/iterations/2/changes?api-version=6.0) which gives us change entries. In your screenshot, like it shows **-2 and +3** between master and current branch details.