# GitHttpClient.GetCommitDiffsAsync gives me latest file content regardless of which commit ID I try with

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs

I have a connection to Azure Devops API

```cs
var conn = new VssConnection(new Uri(uri), new VssBasicCredential("", pat))
```

and create a git client with

```cs
var gitClient = conn.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
```

I get a list of commits with

```cs
var commits = gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(project, repo.Id.ToString(), searchCriteria).WaitForResult();
```

WaitForResult is an extension method like

```
public static class TaskExtension
{
    public static T WaitForResult<T>(this Task<T> task) where T : class
    {
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

Now, for each commit, I want to get the file contents of changed files

```cs
var c2 = gitClient.GetCommitAsync(project: project, commitId: commit.CommitId, repositoryId: repositoryId)
    .WaitForResult();
if (c2.Parents?.Any() ?? false)
{
  var parentCommitId = c2.Parents.First();

  var desc = new GitTargetVersionDescriptor
  {
    Version = commit.CommitId,
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
  };

  var pdesc = new GitBaseVersionDescriptor
  {
    Version = parentCommitId,
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
  };

  var diff = gitClient.GetCommitDiffsAsync(repositoryId: repositoryId,
    project: project, 
    diffCommonCommit: false,
    targetVersionDescriptor: desc, 
    baseVersionDescriptor: pdesc
    ).WaitForResult();

  foreach(var change in diff.Changes)
  {
    if (!change.Item.IsFolder && change.ChangeType == Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType.Edit && change.Item.Path.EndsWith(".vb"))
    {
      var item = gitClient.GetItemAsync(project: project, repositoryId,
        path: change.Item.Path, versionDescriptor: desc, includeContent: true).WaitForResult();
      
      /* here we get file contents in item.Content,
        and we seem to get the same even with the parent descriptor pdesc */
    }
  }
}
```

Why am I not getting the file contents as it was after the commit?
Instead, I always get newest file content.

I have double checked the git hashes and was able to seek the same values in tortoisegit so they are valid.

An example is `e71789c1424ba1ea5c6a9edb5bca4fff1b647185`

If  I put rubbish in `Version` thats not even a sha1 hash, the behavior is the same. I get the newest content (instead of an error message).

Comment: Test on my side, method `GetItemAsync` and `GetItemContentAsync` only returns the source file(not changed file) content.

Answer (score 1):

Test on my side, method `GetItemAsync` and `GetItemContentAsync` only returns the source file(not changed file) content.

As an alternative, we can use rest api to get the **new file**(changed file) content.
[image]

Or you can follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486854/14996050) to get the diff content.

My C# code for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orgname = "orgname";
        var uri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/orgname");
        var personalAccessToken = "PAT";
        var projectName = "projectname";
        var repositoryName = "reponame";
        var pullRequestId = 250; // replace with actual pull request ID

        var credentials = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken);
        var connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials);
        var gitClient = await connection.GetClientAsync<GitHttpClient>();

        var repository = await gitClient.GetRepositoryAsync(projectName, repositoryName);
        var pullRequest = await gitClient.GetPullRequestAsync(repository.Id, pullRequestId);
        var commits = await gitClient.GetPullRequestCommitsAsync(repository.Id, pullRequestId);

        foreach (var commit in commits)
        {
            var c2 = await gitClient.GetCommitAsync(project: projectName, commitId: commit.CommitId, repositoryId: repository.Id);
            if (c2.Parents?.Any() ?? false)
            {
                var parentCommitId = c2.Parents.First();

                var desc = new GitTargetVersionDescriptor
                {
                    Version = commit.CommitId,
                    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
                    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
                };

                var pdesc = new GitBaseVersionDescriptor
                {
                    Version = parentCommitId,
                    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
                    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
                };

                var diff = await gitClient.GetCommitDiffsAsync(repositoryId: repository.Id,
                  project: projectName,
                  diffCommonCommit: false,
                  targetVersionDescriptor: desc,
                  baseVersionDescriptor: pdesc
                  );

                foreach (var change in diff.Changes)
                {
                    if (!change.Item.IsFolder && change.ChangeType == Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType.Edit && change.Item.Path.EndsWith(".vb"))
                    {
                        var parentItemStream = gitClient.GetItemContentAsync(project: projectName, repository.Id, path: change.Item.Path, versionDescriptor: pdesc).Result;

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(parentItemStream))
                        {
                            string parentItemContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine("Old content:");
                            Console.WriteLine(parentItemContent);
                        }

                        // Use HttpClient to make a GET request to the REST API
                        using (var client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}"));
                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Token}");

                            var url = $"https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository.Id}/Items?path={change.Item.Path}&versionDescriptor.version={commit.CommitId}&versionDescriptor.versionType=Commit&includeContent=true";
     
                            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var currentItemContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                Console.WriteLine("New content:");
                                Console.WriteLine(currentItemContent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

You can change the code according to your real pull situation.