# How to get the specific lines that have changed in a commit in an Azure Git Repo using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure-devops

I'm testing the potential of an AI-powered PR reviewer. For this, I need to get the changes in PRs and ask the AI (GPT-4) to review them.

Since I'm using Azure Git repos, I thought that the Azure DevOps SDK would give me the changes. However, as far as I have seen so far, it's limited in functionality and can't do diffing.

For example, using the code below, I can read the contents of the files in which some lines have changed, but I didn't figure out how to fetch only the lines that have changed:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

personal_access_token = os.getenv('PAT')
organization_url = os.getenv('ORG_URL')

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()


project_name = os.getenv('PROJECT_NAME')
repository_id = os.getenv('REPO_NAME') 

# List pull requests
pull_requests = git_client.get_pull_requests(repository_id=repository_id, project=project_name, search_criteria=None)

pr_id = 2  


credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()

# Fetch the PR
pull_request = git_client.get_pull_request(repository_id, pr_id, project=project_name)

# Fetch commits associated with the PR
commits = git_client.get_pull_request_commits(repository_id, pr_id, project=project_name)

print(f"Pull Request ID: {pull_request.pull_request_id}, Title: {pull_request.title}\nCommits:")

for commit in commits:
    print(f"\nCommit ID: {commit.commit_id}")
    # Fetch changes introduced by this commit
    changes = git_client.get_changes(commit_id=commit.commit_id, repository_id=repository_id, project=project_name)
    for change in changes.changes:
            # Assuming 'change' is a dictionary and it contains an 'item' dictionary that has a 'path' key
        item_path = change.get('item', {}).get('path', 'Unknown path')
        print(f"Change: {item_path}")
        if change['changeType']:
            print(f"Change Type: {change['changeType']}")


    if change['changeType'] in ['edit', 'add']:
        # Retrieve the blob content
        blob_content = git_client.get_blob_content(repository_id=repository_id, sha1=change['item']['objectId'], project=project_name)
        # The content is returned as a byte stream
        content_bytes = b''.join(blob_content)

        # Then, decode the bytes to get a string representation of the content
        content_str = content_bytes.decode('utf-8')

        print(content_str)
```

is there a way that I can get only the lines that have changed?

Comment: Hi Federico, have you tried using the workaround below to get the changed lines? Run `Commits - Get Changes` to get commit path and run `Commits - Get` to get parents commit ID. Finally, run the API shared by me with the info got from the previous APIs to get the changed lines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found such a function. As a workaround, you can do it using some REST APIs.

1. Run [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to get commit path via the commit ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

2. Run [Commits - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to get parents commit ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

3. Run the following REST API to get the changed lines.

Request header:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{Project name}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-code-web.file-diff-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "repositoryId": "{Repo ID}",
      "diffParameters": {
        "includeCharDiffs": true,
        "modifiedPath": "{Commit path}",
        "modifiedVersion": "GC{Commit ID}",
        "originalPath": "{Commit path}",
        "originalVersion": "GC{parents commit ID}",
        "partialDiff": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One sample for your reference:

Response body:

[image]

Compare in the UI:

[image]

See the detailed info from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479827/calculate-lines-of-code-change-for-a-commit/65486854#65486854).