# Is there a way to get the raw diff of a commit via the Azure Devops API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

As part of our application, we're building an ability to integrate with Azure DevOps' REST API. One key component that we're interested in is being able to see actual diffs of specific commits, so that we can look at and analyze the line content. We've already created this integration for GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket, and each time it was easy: There's a fairly simple diff endpoint for each that takes in a specific commit ID and diffs it (sometimes with a specific parent commit).

I've not had much luck finding this same functionality in Azure DevOps, however: The [diffs endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#between-commit-ids) has *some* data related to this, but it is really just an overview of which files changed and the high-level nature of those changes, along with the IDs of specific blobs that represent the files in each state (before and after).

It's theoretically possible to use those blobs to manually construct what I'm after, and indeed I've been able to query for the before *and* after blobs to get a diff on each file. But that's two separate endpoint queries per file -- take a twenty-file commit, and suddenly we'd need 40 API calls just to construct a reasonable diff. That doesn't really fit our performance needs, unfortunately.

Is there a separate API endpoint or technique that lets us get to the raw diff? It doesn't need to be a raw diff a la `git diff` directly, just anything that lets us see the before and after state of each *line* (rather than each file) with minimal API calls (preferably just one). I've done much scouring through the docs and here on StackOverflow, and not found anything that accomplishes this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lines of Code modified in each Commit in TFS rest api. How do i get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no existing  Rest API to meet your needs. But you could refer to the following steps to get the content of the git diff.

Step1: You could use the Rest API to [get  the commit id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0
```

Step2: You could use the Rest API to [get the commit by commit id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?changeCount={changeCount}&api-version=5.0
```

In the Rest API Result, you need to record the value of  **“parentsid”, “path”**.

Step3: You could use the following API to get the diff content.

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project /_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters={value}&repositoryId={repositoryid}
```

The {value} is Json type.

Here is  an example:

```
{"originalPath":"filepath","originalVersion":"Parentsid","modifiedPath":"filepath","modifiedVersion":"commitid","partialDiff":true,"includeCharDiffs":true}
```

You could add the value to the API URL.

Then  run the API and  the result will contains the git diff content. (2 means remove, 1 means add)

Here is a result sample:

[image: API Result]

This is [the ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get) I refer to, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that API endpoint, assuming that I'm using it correctly, is returning back a 500 error with "TF10144: 'F' is not a supported version specification type." within some other JSON. The URI we're using is `https://ourorg.visualstudio.com/ourrepo/_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&_repositoryId=<repo uuid>&diffParameters=<the stuff you mentioned>` (the same as the ticket you linked - using the one you mention here makes no difference). There isn't much I can find on Google for this error that actually relates to the API - is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MatthewKloster From the URL , I noticed that there is an extra `_` character before the 'repositoryId'. You could remove it and test the API again(&repositoryId={repoid}).