# Azure DevOps get lines changed per commit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to collect some data to get statistics on my git commits.

Right now I tried the [git commit api route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP)
But it seems to have only the files changed\added and not the actual lines of code that changed, anyone has an idea?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no existing** rest api to get the file change details. But you can use below alternatives to check the diff details:

Option1: check on DevOps UI, you can compare for specific file. You can aslo compare branches if needed.
[image]

Option2: You can use below API to get the file change(you can refer to similar ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61863959/14996050) for your reference.):

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters={value}&repositoryId={repositoryid}
```

The {value} is Json type which contains the file path, parent id, and current path, current commit id, which you can get from rest api [get the commit by commit id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). sample：

```
{"originalPath":"{filepath}","originalVersion":"{parentid}","modifiedPath":"{filepath}","modifiedVersion":"{current commit id}","partialDiff":true,"includeCharDiffs":true}
```

Then run the API and the result will contains the git diff content. (2 means remove, 1 means add, 3 means changed.)

[image]

Option3: you can checkou the repo to local machine, use `git diff` command to check the file changes.

eg: check with parent: `git diff commitid^!`

[image]

Comment: Hi Wade, thanks for your reply !

I want to make an automation to check my productivity in all of my branches so option 1 is not relevant and I want to run it from Azure runbook so option 3 is not relevant sadly.

I must use a REST api, so option 2 will be good for me, but when I use the get commit api I don't get in the response the parameters that you mentioned, any ideas why?
Maybe can you specify the entire URL that you used to get the commit value json?

Comment: @ShaiHoresh, the value json is made up of `filepath`, `parent commit id` and `current commit id`. To get the parameters, my sample url:`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/commits/79efcd3f5289xxxxxfec6ad10fe70407?changeCount=10&api-version=7.1-preview.1`