# Get Lines of Code edited for a Commit in Azure DevOps Rest API: large files edited (changeType==3) don't return full changes

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

when attempting to get the line changes for a very large file (10K+ lines), not all changes are returned. is there a way to paginate the return result? or a different query parameter that can be sent so as to not truncate the response?

url = `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters={params}&repositoryId={repositoryId}`

params (removing spaces) =

```
{
     "originalPath": commit path,
     "originalVersion": parent commit_id,
     "modifiedPath": commit path,
     "modifiedVersion": commit_id,
     "partialDiff": True
}
```

(Expected) sample response (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get) answer):

```
{
     "changeType": 2,
     "mLine": 9,
     "mLines": [],
     "mLinesCount": 0,
     "oLine": 9,
     "oLines": [
       "    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->"
     ],
     "oLinesCount": 1
},
{
      "changeType": 1,
      "mLine": 22,
      "mLines": [
        "      <div>2</div>"
      ],
      "mLinesCount": 1,
      "oLine": 23,
      "oLines": [],
      "oLinesCount": 0
}
```

I am able to get a response. But the response does not include line changes that are found far down the file; this is usually denoted when reviewing the commit via the UI with this warning: "The file is too large to be included in the change summary view. Navigate to the file to view the full diff."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to get all lines in your scenario. As the `top` and `skip` parameter don't work in this api. You may check whether there is `continuationToken` in the response hearder, if there is `continuationToken`, then try to add `continuationToken={continuationToken}` in the api to see whether it works. If there is no `continuationToken`, then there is no way to get all lines in your file as it too large.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cece! Unfortunately, I'm not receiving a `continuationToken` in the response headers.