# Is it possible to fetch commit changes (diff only) via api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to pull commit changes via api and all i get is the path to the file itself, as in the whole file.
What I want to achieve is to see the changes (diff only) for a single file per commit.

E.g:
If i query the same using Github i get the diff like so:
`"@@ -1 +0,0 @@\n- console.log(\"Blasting!\")"`

Is there a similar solution in Azure-devops?
Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to see the changes (diff only) for a single file per commit.

There is no existing  Rest API to meet your needs. But you could refer to the following steps to get the content of the git diff.

Step1: You could use the Rest API to [get  the commit id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0
```

Step2: You could use the Rest API to [get the commit by commit id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=5.0
```

In the Rest API Result, you need to record the value of  **parentsid**.

Step3: You could use the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to Get the file path.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=6.0
```

Step4: You could use the following API to get the diff content.

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project /_api/_versioncontrol/fileDiff?__v=5&diffParameters={value}&repositoryId={repositoryid}
```

The {value} is Json type.

Here is  an example:

```
{"originalPath":"filepath","originalVersion":"Parentsid","modifiedPath":"filepath","modifiedVersion":"commitid","partialDiff":true,"includeCharDiffs":true}
```

You could add the value to the API URL.

Then  run the API and  the result will contains the git diff content. (2 means remove, 1 means add)

Here is a result sample:

[image]

Here is  [the ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get), you could refer to it.

Comment: This needs serious clarity and functional improvements; its not possible to follow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to get the result you are looking for.
For each commit you can use the below API
[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=7.0
```

The response of the above API will contain an array named `changes` which will be a list of all the git objects that got changed by this commit.

Each change will look something like this

```
 {
  item: {
    path: string,
    objectId?: string,
    originalObjectId?: string,
    commitId: string,
    isFolder?: boolean,
    url: string,
  }),
  changeType: 'delete' | 'rename' | 'edit' | 'add' | 'delete, sourceRename' | 'edit, rename',
  sourceServerItem?: string,
}
```

Filter out all the folders and use the `objectId` and `originalObjectId` to fetch the file using the below API [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/blobs/get-blob?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/blobs/{sha1}?api-version=7.0
```

`note: set Accept header to */*`

In this way you will get the previous and the current version of the file

Using the `git-diff` package [Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-diff) you can get the line diff or char diff of the file

Comment: The first link's format is malformed. It isn't clear what the intended format should have been due to some extra encoding. Can you please review and [edit] your answer?

Comment: This just returns the raw file.

Comment: @mwilson yeah. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Commit changes, like the questions asks.

Comment: the end result is what the question asks