# Any public released c# API to get code diff of a given commit

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any public released c# API to get code diff of a given commit?

I did some search and found there is a rest api (fileDiff) can help with it, but seems it is not open to public developers.
[Lines of Code modified in each Commit in TFS rest api. How do i get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get)

Any other alternative way to do it or any plan to release this C# API?

Comment: What kind of source control repo are you using in Azure DevOps? Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official released REST API to get code diff of a given commit yet. You could submit a [User Voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Currently, you would use that unofficial API in the link, or try [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command to show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc.