# how to create a webhook programmatically to check ADO repository has code push

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks

I have find out this called `servicehooks` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops)

But I want to do this programmatically where I have more number of projects and want to check any of that project repository has code push event happened , if yes need to check which files are pushed as a commit.

and based on that push message into my service bus queue.

any sample code for the same? looking for azure function app for above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to code push events using ADO public API: [Subscription create API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

You want your request to look like this:

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json;api-version=4.0" \
  -H "Authorization: Basic $(B64_TOKEN)"
  --request POST \
  --data {
    "publisherId": "tfs",
    "eventType": "git.push",
    "resourceVersion": "1.0",
    "consumerId": "webHooks",
    "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
    "consumerInputs": {"url": $(WEBHOOK_URL)}
  }
  https://dev.azure.com/$(ORGANIZATION)/_apis/hooks/subscriptions
```

This will subscribe you to all code push on **all your repositories of all your projects** of your organization.

When you receive a code push notification ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#git.push)), you can extract the commit ids from the `resource` object (you might need to fetch the Push object [using the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)).

Then you can inspect which file are impacted with the [Commit API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).

If you want to see the file diff, there is also an [undocumented API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713616/lines-of-code-modified-in-each-commit-in-tfs-rest-api-how-do-i-get/41734229#41734229).